# Div doesn't take full height as its child anchors with padding

Tags: html, css

I want to know why an anchor tag with top and bottom padding would not expand its parent div to its full height. e.g here in this fiddle

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="button">Sign Up</a>
  <a href="#" class="button">Login</a>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/exleedo/8qr4srLa/

The parent has grey background and the two buttons are inside this div, but still the div doesn't take the same height as the links.

Comment: Both answers are good but [Flex is not compatible with some of the older browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex), namely IE.

Answer (score 5):

Because of [collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).

You can fix this by adding `display:inline-block` to your links:

```css
.container {
    background: #CCC;
}

.button {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #262626;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:100px">
    <!-- Spacer -->
</div>
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="button">Sign Up</a>
    <a href="#" class="button">Login</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend any inline style (height for that matter) just do this:

```
.container {
background: #CCC;
display: flex;
}
```

**display: flex** will have the auto inner wrap similar to box-sizing